# how to keep my hook on top of the hook chain

Tags: c++, windows, hook

I am working on a school project in which I am writing an application. I'm registering a global hook in windows, I would like to perform changes on events reaching an application.

So currently, I have a global hook installed, but somehow the events are probably reaching the application  first, (based on the synthoms I see), and only afterwards my hook.

I am curious, how do I keep my hook on top of the hook chain? Also, application specific hooks get called first in front of the global hooks?

Edit, adding code (this is how it looks like currently, this obviously doesn't try to re-register the hooks in order to keep it on the top. I had another version where it was re-registering it in a while loop with a sleep, but that didn't work.):

```
int main()
{


HHOOK hhkLowLevelKybd;

    try
    {
        hhkLowLevelKybd = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyBoardProc, 0, 0);

        MSG msg;
        while (!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        cout << "Hook installed" << endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Exception occured. Stopping, uninstalling hook." << endl;
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhkLowLevelKybd);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the code showing how you are installing your hooks?

Comment: You cannot guarantee that your hook is at the top of the chain. Because what if two programs both demanded to be at the top of the chain?

Comment: interesting, I have tried re installing my hook after every 50 ms or so. I think the application has some other way of knowing whether the events are user or API generated. Still, I am curious: how are global hooks prioritized? Do they get called before application defined hooks or they are put in the same queue and whichever was installed last gets called?